# SpringBoot 3, PostGIS:: com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.basic.NullableCharacterType does not define or inherit

Tags: java, spring-boot, postgis, hibernate-6.x, hibernate-types

I am trying to migrate my current spring boot 2 application to 3. I am using PostGIS (I have not set explicit dialect so it uses **org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect**), along with a few jsonb columns. While trying to start up the application after making the necessary changes, I am getting the below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.basic.NullableCharacterType does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.JdbcType getJdbcType()' of interface org.hibernate.type.BasicType.
at org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.applyOrOverwriteEntry(BasicTypeRegistry.java:252) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.register(BasicTypeRegistry.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.register(BasicTypeRegistry.java:223) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeContributions.contributeType(TypeContributions.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.HibernateTypesContributor.contributeType(HibernateTypesContributor.java:118) ~[hibernate-types-52-2.21.1.jar:na]
at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.HibernateTypesContributor.contribute(HibernateTypesContributor.java:96) ~[hibernate-types-52-2.21.1.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:390) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1348) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1419) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
... 103 common frames omitted
```

Below is my pom:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>test</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20230227</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vladmihalcea/hibernate-types-52 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-envers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-spatial -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-json-classic</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.project-lombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

In my POJO, I'm using below columns among others:

```
@jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull(message = "`geometry` is a required field")
@jakarta.persistence.Column(name = "geometry", nullable = false)
private org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry geometry;

@org.hibernate.annotations.JdbcTypeCode(org.hibernate.type.SqlTypes.JSON)
@jakarta.persistence.Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
private Map<String, String> test = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After exploring the repository for hibernate-types on github for the same issue. I found the answer for one of the existing raised issues by the author:

> You're using the wrong Hypersistence Utils dependency.
> ForHibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final, you need to use hypersistence-utils-hibernate-60.

Link to issue : https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils/issues/626

Answer (score 0):

My ${version} of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
    <version>${versioin}</version>
</dependency>
```

works all the way to 2.14.x without any `hypersistence` libraries.

Alternatively, a combo of:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-types-60</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-60</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Works. I'm guessing you need to use the same versioin suffix on both libraries (-60) in my case